# Loading Old Clash of Clans Account

Tags: ios

I recently got a new Iphone, im trying to load the old village I have on my old Iphone, but I have no idea which game center account is linked to my old village. I've tried to sign in to my accounts, but all of them are linked to different villages that I dont want. I made a new account and tried to link my old village to it, but it dosent... I ran out of options

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't remember your email that you synced with the game center for your respective Clash of Clans account I recommend you to address this issue to Clash of Clans support team. They are real helpful and will come up with a solution. To ask them your question follow these steps:

- Open Clash of Clans
- Go to Settings
- Then head to help and support
- On your right hand on top there is new message option select it

Now give them your Clash of Clans in account name, your level(xp), your townhall level and you clan(optional). Then address your issue to them that you want to know the email you synced your game center account with and they will assist you. I hope I helped you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the link with a code option in Clash of Clans?

[image]

Comment: Yeah but each time I try it, it tells me that Im currently not logged in to the game center account that is linked to the village, therefore it dosent let me. Really all I need is a way to figure out which game center account is linked to my village